# Java Thread Concurrent Read and Write

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I have a arraylist which store data i received and transmit asynchronously over bluetooth.

I have a write thread and a read thread to access the arraylist. I am trying to simulate bluetooth echo (The bluetooth is to echo back everything i send).

```
private class ReadThread extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
        while(!isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
                if (mInputStream == null) return;
                size = mInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (size == 64) {
                    if (bufferList.isEmpty()){
                        Log.i("AOK Fail","Nothing to AOK");
                    }

                    if (compareByte(buffer,bufferList.get(0) == true) // Compare data in this 2 byte array
                          bufferList.remove(0);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
}

private class WriteThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    super.run();
    while(!isInterrupted()) {

        try {
            count++;
            if (bufferList.isEmpty() == false && count < 3){    
                write(bufferList.get(0));       
                count = 0;
            }else{
                // Drop data after 3 fail attempt
                bufferList.remove(0);
                count=0;
            }               

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

On button pressed i will send data . It works fine if i transmit slowly. However it fails when i start to click rapidly (queue data for transmission). Once i received a AOK Fail message . All remaining data will all be AOK Fail even newly add data. Why is that so

If it is a threading issue shouldn't it be resolve after all data is transmitted ?

Comment: How are bufferList and count declared?  It doesn't look, from what I can see, as if they are properly synchronized...

Answer (score 1):

This bufferList variable is a thread safe object? like an array blocking list or something? If not you may be having some problems trying to add/remove itens simultaneously.

This would cause an exception in the producer Thread, nothing else would be transmitted you'd get the "Nothing to AOk" log.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear how this code works because it does not include some details:

- How are you feeding `bufferList` and which is its type? Maybe the ArrayList you mentioned in your question? ArrayList is not thread safe see [ArrayList documentation for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).
- What `write` method does?
- What `compareByte` method does? It seems obvious, but it will be good to take a look at the code, you know, just in case (also you are missing a bracket).
- Where is the `count` var you are using inside WriteThread class declared? Are you incrementing `count` value outside this code? If that's true, you may be removing all contents from `bufferList` variable when `count >= 3` (else block). And if you do this, the first part of your `bufferList.isEmpty() == false && count < 3` condition can be false at some time because your `bufferList` will be empty; then you will execute the else block, trying to remove an element from an empty ArrayList, your code will throw an IndexOutOfBoudsException (see the [ArrayList remove method documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29)) and your WriteThread will be aborted.